# how to get latest post on channel with link

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

i have a bot and want to get last posts from a telegram channel that isn't joined on in. if that's bot add into channel administrator it's possible, but It is not possible for me.
how should i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible with current [Telegram Bots APIs](https://core.telegram.org). 
The bot must be **administrator** of the channel to handle channel posts.